# Markdown in chat "room description"

Tags: feature-request, chat

Greetings guardians of the unicorns,

I noticed that markdown links don't render as expected in the room info.

It's only a small thing but thought I would bring it to your attention.

**UPDATE**

In response to comments: Raw URLs do link; however, the `[description](url)` syntax doesn't work

Comment: Could you explain the "why"? What's the gain from allowing Markdown there?

Comment: Room info right now looks like this: "Tales of the fight between green robots and nyan cats, in the realm of Unicornia. We can teach you to fish, but we're not giving out free tuna. Read the House Rules! mainerror.github.com/android-room-rules" - Would be much prettier to hyperlink the text "Read the House Rules!" (as well as drawing attention to it for first time users)

Comment: @balpha, to link directly to official docs and other help-vampire pamphlets in a permanent location

Comment: You can already put URLs into the room description and they will by hyperlinked in the in-room view.

Comment: @balpha: That's true, but you can't give them a text, and that's a boo boo.

Comment: I’d like to bring some attention to this again; we would like to put some links in the channel description but having to include them as full URLs is unncessarily verbose and doesn’t look nice.

Comment: I too would like markdown in the room descriptions, +1x1000

Comment: Are there any plans to make this happen? In contrast to the rest of SO, the fact that the chat room description _cannot_ use markdown seems kinda inconsistent and primitive. I too would like to use link text for URLs.

Comment: Inspired by the ugliness of [this description](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers).

Comment: @acheong87 good luck with that bounty... I had a 100 rep bounty on it expire a couple of days ago... I hope this one gets some proper attention... It's not like it's a massive feature request... the whole blooming site breaths markdown and it works for chat messages, so it's not like it's a big deal! :)

Comment: @JonClements - I see. And I agree. I'll consider it a success if I can drive even a few more upvotes toward this request. Maybe at a certain threshold the devs will give it a little more attention.

Comment: @balpha, "What's the gain from allowing Markdown there?" - __Consistency__

Answer (score 9):

We should do our best to have **consistency** as much as possible on this site.  Having the same markdown or mini-markdown syntax work across all elements would be a step in the right direction.  Everywhere we input text, we should be able to use one of the markdown types.

Comment: But not in the tag excerpt, HTML doesn't work in the tag pop-up UI.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, yep, you're right, no markdown in the tag excerpt

Comment: Has it been done yet? Or are we still waiting for it to happen?