# Formatting in chat room description

Tags: feature-request, chat, markdown

Can Markdown formatting be added to chat descriptions?

Sometimes bold text would be nice, to highlight something in the description.

Comment: Do you have a specific example of where this would be useful?

Comment: @DannyBeckett For example, making "Don't ask to ask, just ask" bold - most people don't see things like that.

Comment: Yeah, it should have a limited markdown. The same makrdown used for comments should work fine.

Comment: I agree. Everyday a new user comes to the chat and asks "May I ask a question?", then waits until someone replies to actually ask a question.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138813/187954

Comment: @RaghavSood This may be a duplicate, but that question hasn't had any activity in a year.